# UIViewController in navigation controller AND presenting modally

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller

I'm hoping this is an easy one...

I want to replicate what happens in the Contacts app in iOS. The contacts app uses a navigation controller to load a contact's details, great. If you then edit the contact, it will change the buttons in the nav controller as well all the fields on the screen, but it's still operating under the nav controller.

If you create a new contact from the main contact list, you'll get the same edit screen in the form of a modal screen presented over top of your list. This way has a toolbar or something at the top containing your buttons and what not.

How do I replicate this without creating 2 view controller containing the same fields but with one of them having a toolbar?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: create your viewController first.Have a BOOL property in your view controller something like this `shouldHideToolBar` . Turn it YES or  NO basing on where you are calling from. In your viewController try to write the code to Hide the show basing on this flag in your `viewControllerWillAppear()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably create an instance variable to denote which mode the controller is in. Perhaps a BOOl property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isEditingMode) BOOL editingMode;
```

In cases like this I generally create an initializer that takes this as an argument:

```
- (id)initWithEditingMode:(BOOL)editingMode;
```

Then all you have to do is use the value of this BOOL to decide what to do with your UI. If you are using a xib file, include your toolbar and then in viewDidLoad hide the toolbar if editingMode is YES.

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. I wasn't sure if there was another way where the showing and hiding of the toolbar could be handled automatically, but I guess not. This is perfect.